# Matrix class input operator overloading >> in C++

Tags: c++, matrix, input, overloading, operator-keyword

I created a matrix class which contains an vector of vectors of a point object (another class i made). Every point in the matrix is walkable or not walkable (the matrix is actually a maze). 1 is walkable, 0 is not.
I want to get the matrix in this form:
4 4 //size of the maze (matrix)
1 0 1 0 (enter)
1 1 0 0 (enter)
0 1 1 0 (enter)
1 0 1 1 (enter)

I tried to get row by row, and then seperate the points (1s and 0s) by stream string. This is my code:

```
    istream & operator >> (istream& input, maze inMaze) {

string rowStream;
string tmpWord;
int num, colCounter; //num = 1 or 0, colCounter = col index

for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < inMaze.rowsSize; rowIndex++){ //over the rows 
    int colIndex = 0;
    bool isWalkable;
    input >> rowStream; //input to string
    stringstream seperateWord(rowStream); //string to stream string

    while (seperateWord >> tmpWord) { //sstring seperate space bars in                          string, reprasant a row

        if (tmpWord == "0") isWalkable = false; //in maze matrix, zero means not a path
        else if (tmpWord == "1") isWalkable = true; //else 1 = a path
        else throw "invalid input"; //wrong input (num in matrix not 0 nor 1)
        inMaze.getMaze[rowIndex][colIndex].setPoint(rowIndex, colIndex, isWalkable); //set point in maze
        colIndex++; //next col
    } //done filling a row, to next row
}
```

}

It didnt work. It always ended getting the input after the first row, and filled everything with 1s.
What did I do wrong?

Thank you for your help! and sorry for my poor English.. :-)

Comment: You should take the matrix parameter by reference, not value copy: `istream & operator >> (istream& input, maze& inMaze) {`

Comment: Next time asking here care to exactly explain what's _not working_, also provide a [MCVE] as required in the sites policies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in line `input >> rowStream;` replace it with `getline(input,line);` and `line` is `string` type.

the operator `>>` of file take one argument ended with white space!

like: `00 1 0 11`, first argument is `00`, second is `1`...

and in your case using `stringstream` which mean you must take whole `line`

like: `0 1 0 1 0 1`, take it using getline, then use `stringstream` to get right input. `0` then `1` ...